# MySQL - Matching parameters in LIKE statements across multiple WHERE statements

Tags: mysql

I'd like to run a query against a database using two LIKE statements.

eg.

```
SELECT row FROM table WHERE field1 LIKE 'value_%_topic' AND field2 LIKE 'value_%_name'
```

I'd like to be able to match the %'d parameters so that a row matching value_1_topic and value_1_name would return, but value_2_topic and value_3_name would not.

Is this possible?

I'm running this against a WordPress wp_postmeta table, using ACF's repeater field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably something like this?

```
SELECT row FROM table WHERE field1 LIKE 'value_%_topic' AND field2 LIKE 'value_%_name' AND SUBSTRING(field1, 7, 1) = SUBSTRING(field2, 7, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use the substring_index function to achieve this:

```
SELECT row FROM table 
WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(field1,'_',0)='value_' 
AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(field2,'_',0)='value_' 
AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(field1,'_',1)=SUBSTRING_INDEX(field2,'_',1) 
AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(field1,'_',-1)='topic'
AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(field2,'_',-1) ='name';
```